# Nextcloud client complains about missing keychain at startup

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-keyring, nextcloud

I have a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

Every time I turn on the PC the nextcloud client complains that it doesn't know how to login to my server, because it says there is no keychain available.

How do I automatically unlock the keychain so it can work?

```
snap info nextcloud-client
name:      nextcloud-client
summary:   Nextcloud Desktop Client
publisher: nextcloud
license:   unknown
description: |
  The Nextcloud Desktop Client is a tool to synchronize files from Nextcloud
  Server with your computer.
commands:
  - nextcloud-client.cmd
  - nextcloud-client
snap-id:   qRAMgnTMeyTaHngceQL4vFJf5mOl9uV1
tracking:  stable
refreshed: 2017-12-11T14:01:10+01:00
installed:   2.3.3+gitab40efe (10) 93MB -
channels:                          
  stable:    2.3.3+gitab40efe (10) 93MB -
  candidate: ↑                          
  beta:      ↑                          
  edge:      2.3.3+git3a48c7c (21) 99MB -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around on the internet, I've found [this topic](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/nextcloud-client-snap-doesnt-remember-password/4270), with a possible solution. Please read the topic for the security implication of the approach.

The solution is running in a terminal:

```
snap connect nextcloud-client:password-manager-service
```

or you can use the software center as well:

[image: permissions]

Comment: Any ideas on Linux Mint?